# Get info about file

Tags: php, file-upload

I have next form data:

```
var myData = new FormData();
          myData.append ( 'file', mUpload);

$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "map_process.php",
          processData: false, 
          contentType: false, 
          data: myData,
          success:function(data){
          console.log(data);
```

PHP side:

```
if($_POST) 
{
$etc = print_r($_POST['file']);
die($etc);
}
```

console log : `[object FileList]1`

if i `print_r($_FILES)`

console log : `Array()1`

What does it mean? How to get info about file?

Comment: Did you try using $_FILES function?

Comment: It means the `$_POST['file']` is an empty array and `$etc` is `1`. Typically info about file locations in PHP is in the `$_FILES` (super)global and you can get more file details with `file_info` if you give it the filename.

Comment: This means that the file does not reach the file map_process.php?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use:

```
if(isset($_POST)) 
{

var_dump($_POST['file']);

}
```

And also you could add to the ajax call: "async: true" - optional

**Update:**

Since your result is an object, try to foreach it like so:

```
$file = $_POST['file'];

foreach($file as $f){
    echo $f;
}
```

Comment: var_dump : string(17) "[object FileList]"

Comment: That is an object not an array so you need to foreach it. I will update my answer.

Comment: <b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/#/map_process.php</b> on line <b>31</b><br />

Comment: Can you please post your full code ? including the form you are using ? Because you are doing something wrong, and I want to see what

Comment: Well that`s a messy code, but I can see the file name is "pUpload", are you sure the file is actually submitting ? and please remove these:  "processData: false, contentType: false"

Comment: if i remove these : processData: false, contentType: false, i have a next error : Illegal invocation.

i have 2 console.log for mUpload. After : var mUpload = $('input.save-upload')[0].files;  console log tell me (FileList {0: File, length: 1})

and before var myData = new FormData(); console. log ([object FileList])

Comment: All I can see is that FileList is an object, and it has a lenght of 1, without a working example I cannot debug and help you..